# Finding similar matricies

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm trying to find a matrix N similar to the scalar matrix M =
$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        a & 0 \\
        0 & a \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$
Such that $M = ANA^{-1}$. I have no idea where to start? To me it doesn't appear such a matrix would exist, but I don't know how to prove it.

Also, if I were to change the matrix M to
$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        a_1 & 0 \\
        0 & a_2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$
would it then be possible to find N similar to M?

Comment: Hint: The first $M$ commutes with all 2x2 matrices. The second $M$ does not.

Answer (score 0):

It means that you want :

$M = a*I =N*A*N^{-1} => A = a*N^{-1}*I*N = a*I = M$ So in this case there is only one solution.

For the second case, all you have to do is find a diagonalizable matrix with the coefficient of M as eigenvalues :

$X_A(X)=X^2 -tr(A)*X +det(A)=(X-a_1)*(X-a_2)$
     $ =X^2 -(a_1+a_2)*X +a_1*a_2$
For instance, we can take:
$$N = \begin{pmatrix}
        a_1 +a_2 & -a_2 \\
        a_1 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

I'll let you find the good A matrix, which exists at least.

Comment: Sorry, still trying to figure this stuff out. What is X? And how did you get to N? Also, have no idea how to find a "good" matrix...?

Comment: X is the undefinite variable used to represent a polynomial. You can replace it by real numbers, or a Matrix for instance if you use the right notations (polynomials of Matrix). Do you know the characteristic polynomial? And the theorem of Cayley-Hamilton? $X_A$ is the characteristic polynomial of A, and $X_A(A) = 0 = A^2 -tr(A)*X + det(A)*I$. All I did to find N is identification

Comment: If you've never studied diagonalization, I'll have to change my answer or adapt it. But such a question should be treated using this notions, it's very fluid and easy to manipulate

Comment: Yes, I believe this is ahead of where I'm currently at. Currently just at the stage of computing the minimal polynomial. Don't know how to use that to determine what N and A are. Technically, haven't even gotten to Eigen values, so don't know if I can use that?

Comment: Ok I see, it's not complicated. The roots of the minimal polynomial are the eigenvalues of A, and a theorem says that if A has as much different eigenvalues as its size ( A being a square matrix) then it has a basis of eigenvectors, ie it is a diagonal matrix in a certain base. That's a way to say : There is a invertible matrix P and a diagonal matrix D such as :
$ P^{-1}*A*P = D $
Now  in dimension two your minimal polynomial is your characteristic polynomial if A is not of the form a*I, so all you have to do is identify the coefficients of A using the formula giving $X_A$ I used above